# Bulk Import query is not working in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to run this bulk import query and i keep getting the same error 'incorrect syntax near 'with'' The query is:

```
BULK INSERT 
   [ Centra . [ dbo] .
   [ InfoHeader ] 
   FROM '‪C:\Share\092013-DB.txt' 
    [ WITH 
    ( 
   [ [ , ] BATCHSIZE = 10000000 ] 
   [ [ , ] CHECK_CONSTRAINTS ] 
   [ [ , ] CODEPAGE =  'OEM' ]
   [ [ , ] DATAFILETYPE =  'char']
   [ [ , ] FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t' ] 
   [ [ , ] FIRSTROW = 1 ] 
   [ [ , ] FIRE_TRIGGERS ] 
   [ [ , ] KEEPIDENTITY ] 
   [ [ , ] KEEPNULLS ] 
   [ [ , ] KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH = kilobytes_per_batch ] 
   [ [ , ] LASTROW = 0 ] 
   [ [ , ] MAXERRORS = 100 ] 
   [ [ , ] ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ] 
   [ [ , ] ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n' ]  
   [ [ , ] ERRORFILE = 'C:\bulkimportlog.txt' ] 
   )]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[ WITH ... ]` syntax means that `WITH ...` is *optional*.

The square brackets is not part of the syntax, they're meant to signal that the enclosed portion of the syntax can be left out.

You can see what all the symbols mean in the documentation here: [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx).

Here's your edited SQL (untested):

```
BULK INSERT Centra.dbo.InfoHeader
FROM '‪C:\Share\092013-DB.txt' 
WITH 
( 
    BATCHSIZE = 10000000,
    CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
    CODEPAGE =  'OEM',
    DATAFILETYPE =  'char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIRE_TRIGGERS,
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    KEEPNULLS,
    KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH = kilobytes_per_batch, -- need number here
    LASTROW = 0,
    MAXERRORS = 100,
    ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch,           -- and here
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\bulkimportlog.txt'
)
```

Also, since most of these things are optional, you may not need nor want them all to be present in the statement, and if you leave them at the default values I would rather take them out and make the statement easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for advice on the default values. I took your suggestion. And am still coming up with an error. This is the new query:

       BULK INSERT 
       [ Centra . [ dbo] .
       [ InfoHeader ] 
       FROM '‪C:\Share\092013-DB.txt' 
       WITH 
       ( 
       [ [ , ] BATCHSIZE = 10000000 ] 
       [ [ , ] CHECK_CONSTRAINTS ]  
       [ [ , ] KEEPIDENTITY ] 
       [ [ , ] KEEPNULLS ] 
       [ [ , ] MAXERRORS = 100 ]   
       [ [ , ] ERRORFILE = 'C:\bulkimportlog.txt' ] 
       )

The error is:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ' [ , '.

Comment: its coming up with syntax where it says batchsize

Comment: You need to remove the square brackets, they're not part of what you have to write. Start with the statement I wrote and remove bits from that.

Comment: Ok yes i misunderstood the first time. But i removed all of the brackets and the error i am getting now is:

Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot bulk load because the file "‪‪C:\092013.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

Comment: So figure out why the file cannot be opened. There's nothing more we can help you with here now. Do you have the file on the server?